# Problems with clang cross-compiling ardupilot

Tags: c++, clang, cross-compiling

First I tried the following command

```
`CC=clang CXX=clang++ CXXFLAGS="-O0 -g --target=arm-none-eabi -I/opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi-10-2020-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/include/c++/10.2.1 -I/opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi-10-2020-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/include/c++/10.2.1/arm-none-eabi -I/opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi-10-2020-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/include/c++/10.2.1/backward -I/opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi-10-2020-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.2.1/include -I/opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi-10-2020-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.2.1/include-fixed -I/opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi-10-2020-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/include"  ./waf configure --board=CUAVv5 `
```

Cross-compiling ardupilot gives the following error

> "clang: fatal error: unknown argument: '-mno-thumb-interwork'"

Thereupon I removed the -mno-thumb-interwork compilation option from CUAVv5_cache.py and continued compiling, and again the following error occurred:

> "/opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi-10-2020-q4-major/bin/...
> /lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.2.1/... /... /... /...
> /arm-none-eabi/include/c++/10.2.1/cstdio:98:11: fatal error: no member
> named 'FILE' in the global namespace   using ::FILE;"

I further modified CUAVv5_cache.py to include '--sysroot=/opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi-10-2020-q4-major/bin/... /arm-none-eabi' was removed to continue compiling and ended up with the following error:

> "fatal error: out-of-line definition of 'lseek' does not match any
> declaration in 'AP_Filesystem_FATFS' off_t
> AP_Filesystem_FATFS::lseek(int fileno, off_t position, int whence)"

Obviously so far the cross compilation is failing, can anyone tell me how to implement cross compilation ardupilot?
I want to analyze ardupilot statically using llvm.